# Which one of them is the faster?

Tags: c++, std

first sorry for my poor English.

I want to know Which one of them is the faster

```
set_name.lower_bound(key) ;
```

or

```
lower_bound(set_name.begin() , set_name.end() , value)
```

I try to know which one of them is the faster.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound#Complexity

Comment: @Mansoor i try both of them on some problems in codeforces and the second one gives me timelimit for lager constrains and accepted for the first one so i think the difference is not negligable

Comment: @TTMED If you researched your question (which is good), then you should include your findings in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt you should perform an analysis of the runtime. However, assuming your `set_name` variable has type `std::set<T>` for some `T`, `std::lower_bound` is most likely going to lose against `std::set<T>::lower_bound`.

Why? The latter can use the underlying structure of the rb-tree while the former cannot. In particular, `std::lower_bound` uses something akin to [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). For data structures like an `std::vector` advance is a constant-time operation (more specifically: a pointer-integer addition). However, for something like an `std::set<T>`, advance is linear in time, with some hefty pointer indirection and likely repeated cache misses, making it extremely slow to run repeatedly on large containers.

So, if you have a set-like structure, use the `lower_bound` member structure as it is specifically optimised for that data structure.